# Google one tap login with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

in one of my projects i want to add a google one tap login for that i followed instructions as mentioned.
The front end is working fine but there is issue with the backend.

Here is my code.
I have added this script to the header.

and this code after body open

```
<div id="g_id_onload" 
data-client_id="#####################.googleusercontent.com" 
data-login_uri="/login/google/oneTap" 
data-_token="{{csrf_token()}}" 
data-method="post"
data-ux_mode="redirect"
data-auto_prompt="true">        
</div>
```

This is the route

```
Route::get('/login/google/oneTap', [App\Http\Controllers\SocialLoginController::class, 'oneTap']);
```

In an article regarding one, tap login author told that it requires a post method but there is clarification on how to add a post method.
This is the article.
https://www.teachnep.com/blog/how-to-add-one-tap-login-to-laravel-project#

My backend code.

```
public function oneTap(REQUEST $request)
    {
        $token = $request->credential;
        $tokenParts = explode('.', $token);
        $tokenHeader = base64_decode($tokenParts[0]);
        $tokenPayload = base64_decode($tokenParts[1]);
        $jwtHeader = json_decode($tokenHeader);
        $jwtPayload = json_decode($tokenPayload);
        $user = $jwtPayload;
        return $user;
    }
```

It returns null;
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You must define your route using the `POST` verb instead of `GET`.

For example:

```
Route::post('/login/google', [GoogleSignInController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('login.google');
```

Even though you can verify the "**ID Token**" (this is how Google refers to the `credential` param) by yourself, it is recommended to use the official **Google API Client Library**.

You can add it to your project using Composer:

```
composer require google/apiclient
```

In addition to validate the `credential` field, you should validate the **CSRF token** provided in the `g_csrf_token` field.

To summarize:

```
/**
 * Validate the "ID Token" using the Google API Client Library.
 * https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if ($_COOKIE['g_csrf_token'] !== $request->input('g_csrf_token')) {
        // Invalid CSRF token
        return back();
    }
    
    $idToken = $request->input('credential'); 
        
    $client = new Google_Client([
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID')
    ]);
    
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($idToken);
    
    if (!$payload) {
        // Invalid ID token
        return back();
    }
    
    dd($payload);
}
```

Note that I printed the `$payload` at the end:

[image: Google One Tap - Payload response]

You may want to use the `$payload['sub']` that represents the user id to register / authenticate this user in your application, as well as its `name` and `picture`.

Comment: You sir, saved me from a lot of head banging for trying to tame this beast. Thank you.